# Add text with grey background to pictures like Snapchat does? Android/Java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, paint

```
          Bitmap newBm = ...
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBm);
          Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
          paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          paint.setTextSize((int) (44 * scale));
          Rect bounds = new Rect();
          paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
          canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);
```

I drew text on the Bitmap like so. How could I get a grey background that is the same height as the text but covers the whole screen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Rect`. Before drawing the text draw the `Rect` to the screen:

`int screenWidth = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
Rect greyBack = new Rect(0,top,screenWidth,bottom);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setARGB(128, 100, 100, 100); //added alpha because Snapchat has translucent //grey background
canvas.drawRect(greyBack, paint);`

`top` and `bottom` need to be coordinates above and below the text. You could use `y`'s value and take away a bit for `top` and add a bit for `bottom`. How much you add/subtract is up to you and changes the height of the `greyBack` background.

Comment: Thanks! this is the answer I ended up using.

Comment: Can you please accept it as the answer of it solved your problem by clicking the tick under the upvote arrow

Comment: Done. Sorry Im a noob. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Lol don't worry - everyone starts somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see and learn how these sort of things are done with well written code is to look at the android source code itself. For example here is the [onDraw method for a TextView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) it includes additional stuff you won't probably need like compoundPadding, but you can follow it through and get the basic concept of how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used another answer but Im reading up on the onDraw method as well so I appreciate it